# perform ping test to change dns

Tags: shell-script, dns

I wrote this script to check if my dns server works fine or not, and if not change it. but it gives out error `./dns-ping.sh: line 15: ((: 3 < : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< ")`

where is the problem?

```
#! /bin/bash

loss_count=0
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "++ DNS Ping Tester ++"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "please enter threshold:"
read $threshold
for timer in {1..2}
    do
        png=`ping -c 5 -q yahoo.com | grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)'`
        let loss_count=$png+$loss_count
done
let loss_mid=loss_count/12
if (($loss_mid < $threshold)); then
#   ifdown eth0
    echo "less"
else
    echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
fi
```

Comment: You want to replace < with -lt, which stands for "less than".

Comment: Looks like you executed this script using `sh` rather than `bash`.

Comment: @schaiba actually the `<` is perfectly valid bash when used inside `(( ))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the following line:

```
if (($loss_mid < $threshold)); then
```

By this one:

```
if [ "$loss_mid" -lt "$threshold" ]; then
```

Comment: now it gives this error:  ./dns-ping.sh: line 15: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: This modification works for me. `$threshold` has to be a numeric variable.